# Font not displaying - Warning: incompatible embedded font 'myFont' specified for spark.components::Label

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

Up until recently the font was embedding successfully in my application. After something hosed the SDK and I did a reinstall of the SDK the embedded font is no longer displaying. It's giving this error:

> warning: incompatible embedded font 'myFont' specified for
>   spark.components::Label (Label4505) . This component requires that the
>   embedded font be declared with embedAsCFF=true.

But the font is embedded using CFF true:

```
@font-face {
    src:url("../../fonts/MyFonts/MyFont-Regular.ttf");
    fontWeight:normal;
    fontFamily:myFont;
    embedAsCFF:true;
}
```

Note: This was working before.

Comment: Did you reinstall the same SDK version as previously ? If not check the release notes of the new SDK to see if anything changed with respect to embedded fonts.